# Oracle SQL/PL - ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: oracle, date

I get the error message: ORA-01843: not a valid month after executing a sql plus script.
I try using the "standard" date format yyyy-mm-dd.
Is SQL/PL not understanding the alter session statement?

```
set linesize 200
set pagesize 1000
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd';

select
 *
from my_table
where  
date >= '2019-08-31';

exit
```

Comment: What is the data type of your "date" column?  ("DATE" is a reservered word, so I seriously doubt that is the actual name of the column).  Please update your question to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What interface are you using? SQL Developer? Toad? PLSQL Developer? Some of these use their own NLS parameters and don't honor your `ALTER SESSION`. In any case, the correct solution is to add the keyword `date` before the string on the right-hand side, which converts it from a text literal to a date literal. Date literals require the `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format (no other format can be used for date literals), and does not depend on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do need - from my point of view - is not to compare date values to strings.

Presuming that `date` here actually represent a `DATE` datatype column (why didn't you post table description?) (as already commented, you can't name a column that way, not unless you enclosed its name into double quotes), then

```
where date >= '2019-08-31'
      ----    ------------
      DATE     this is a string
    datatype
```

Use date literal, which always has a `DATE` keyword and date in format `'yyyy-mm-dd'`:

```
where date >= date '2019-08-31'
```

Or, use `to_date` function with appropriate format mask:

```
where date >= to_date('2019-08-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

---

If `date` column (wrong name, as we already know) actually contains strings and you *hope* all of them are following the `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format, well, some values don't. Storing dates into `varchar2` datatype column is almost always a bad idea. Nobody prevents you from storing e.g. `'2019-ac-31'` into it, and that isn't a valid date value.